# How do I render <li> side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm looking to create a navigation menu with list items rendered in one line.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 50):

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

**EDIT:** I now realize why I felt strange answering with `display: inline`: because I usually use `float: left` myself instead, which is anthony-arnold's answer (so to him goes my upvote!).

Anyway, while either method will cause your `li`s to display in one line, inline elements and floated elements do behave differently. Depending on how you've styled your layout, you may have to choose one or the other.

Comment: Floated elements can still be block-level (in fact, they're ALWAYS treated as block-level) and so you can still apply box model properties like padding and margin to them. Inline elements ignore padding/margin, so float: left is usually the best solution. In fact, if you use BOTH, it will correct a bug in IE6 that causes floated elements to have double margins (though all browsers will still render them as block-level).

Answer (score 19):

You could also do this, for some situations:

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This would not work for odd number of elements

Answer (score 12):

My favorite way to do it it's by using because it's allow do use width, height, margins and padding:

```
li { display: inline-block; }
```

But have some render problem in IE, to fix use (order is important):

```
li 
{ 
  display: inline-block; 
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the best resources on the subject is http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/ (a little outdated though).

They suggest both `li {display: inline;}`  and `li {float: left;}` depending on the effect you want.

Look for example their "Simple horizontal list" http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
ul {
    float: right;  to <li> go to the Right or Left side
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

If you use the "float:" in the "li", the list will invert the sequency.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {display: inline;} 
ul li { list-style: none;display: inline;}
```

Comment: +1.. I was wondering. Why didn't anyone mention the list-style: none. It is needed right? Or bullet points will appear horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

If you want to maintain it's block characteristics but still need side-by-side, you could do:

```
li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't floating an element automatically cause it to `display: block`? Or is it still overridable?

Comment: @BoltClock: You could use either `display:inline` or `float:left` but using float saves you from display getting screwed up in IE<=7, however, this depends on your html markup, using both together is better in most cases.

Comment: Ah, sounds like an IE issue after all.

Comment: Just to add some clarification, it's actually the addition of display:inline that corrects the IE <= 6 bug. And yes Bolt, floating will cause an element to be treated as display: block. IE6 will do weird things with the margin if you don't in turn specify display: inline (confusing, because IE6 will STILL render it as block-level, just will not screw up the margins).

Answer (score 1):

you will try this styling

```
li{
height:20px;
float:left;
list-style-type: none;
width:70px;
padding:3px;
border-right:1px solid #3687AF;
background-color: #015287;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 30px;
}
```

it will work for u sure...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `float: left;`

```
ul li {
    float: left;
}
```